# How to choose a radio button when the radio buttons have the same id but have different values using capybara

Tags: capybara

Below is the html code for two radio buttons, they only differ by "value" attribute

```
<input id="AmountOption" name="AmountOption" type="radio" value="1">
<input id="AmountOption" name="AmountOption" type="radio" value="2">
```

What Im trying to do is to choose the radio button with "value =2 "

I tried using "choose("AmountOption")" which choses the first radio button, but i want to choose the second radio button

How can i achieve this with "choose("")" method provided by capybara.

Any other alternatives are also welcome.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The id of an element should identify that element uniquely. This means your html is not valid right now. Can you change the id?

Answer (score 6):

Look at [implementation of `choose`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#choose-instance_method):

```
def choose(locator, options={})
  find(:radio_button, locator, options).set(true)
end
```

So it's obvious that you should invoke method `set` on some element.

`:radiobutton` selector supports only `id`, `name` and `label` so you can't use it and should use some other selector type:

```
find('#AmountOption[value=2]').set(true) # selector type is :css by default
```

Comment: Found a better solution for selecting the second radio button. I used "browser.find_element("//input[@value='2']").click " . The radio button selected using this. Anyways Thanks for your answer Andrey :-)

Comment: @Kalyan an equivalent of `page.driver.browser.find_element("//input[@value='2']").click` is `find(:xpath, "//input[@value='2']").click`